# Why here we annotate class with @Autowire

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I came across this code

```
   @Singleton
    @Controller
    @Autowire(mode = AutowireMode.BY_NAME)
    @Path("/")
    public class RootResource {
    }
```

I have seen @Autowire on fields, 
It means autowiring by type, and class with this field will get bean with particular type.

But in above code I am not sure who is using this RootResource bean?

This is Spring-jersey Rest project.

What I understand is spring will create bean of RootResource and `Some class` will use this bean to set its property. (I cant see any explicit configuration for this bean)

My question is,

1) Who is this class?

2) Here Autowiring by name is done, Can I replace @Autowired with @Resource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of @Autowire in this case is to instruct the Spring container to inject dependencies into RootResource by using beans with names matching property names in RootResource.

This is similar to that autowire attribute of the bean element using XML configuration. Assuming RootResource has

```
@Singleton
@Controller
@Autowire(mode = AutowireMode.BY_NAME)
@Path("/")
public class RootResource{

   private SomeService someService;

   private AnotherService anotherService;

   public void setSomeService(SomeService someService){
      this.someService = someService;
   }

   public void setAnotherService(AnotherService anotherService){
      this.anotherService = anotherService;
   }

 }
```

The container will attempt to find beans named someService and anotherService and will try to set the corresponding properties. Take note you don`t require any dependency inject annotations the property or field level.

You can use @Resource / @Autowired to achieve the same thing. However you have to annotate the fields or setters in this case. And also injection will fail if the dependency is not found in the container

@Singleton
    @Controller
    @Autowire(mode = AutowireMode.BY_NAME)
    @Path("/")
public class RootResource{

```
   private SomeService someService;

   private AnotherService anotherService;

   @Resource
   public void setSomeService(SomeService someService){
      this.someService = someService;
   }

   @Resource
   public void setAnotherService(AnotherService anotherService){
      this.anotherService = anotherService;
   }

 }
```

@Resource will use bean name and fall back to type matching whilst @Autowired always uses type matching

Also note that @Autowire and @Autowired have different behaviour. The RootResource bean does not need to be explictly configured in the application context. It will be auto detected by the component scanner as it has a stereotype annotation i.e @Controoler